# I am trying to fetch data from real-time database firebase in flutter for app. So, I have tried couple ways but couldn't make it work

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from real-time database firebase in flutter for app. So, i have tried couple ways but couldn't make it work.

These are my current codes for retrieving data from realtime database  :

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      query: databaseRef,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
          Animation<double> animation, int index) {
        var x = snapshot.value;
        if (snapshot != null) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(x['name']),
            subtitle: Text(x['city']),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.male),
              onPressed: () {
                var keyFinder = snapshot.key;
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: keyFinder!);
              },
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(child: Text("Empty data found"));
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: image showing the error]

it show error here `title: Text(x['name'])`, saying:

> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
> Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A snapshot can have no value, so when you do this:

```
var x = snapshot.value;
```

Your `x` variable can either be `null` or hold the value of the node. When you try to access a subvalue from `x`, the compiler warns you can `x` may be `null`.

One way to tell it that it isn't by adding an `!`:

```
title: Text(x!['name']),
```

I actually don't like that all that much, and typically prefer ensuring the correct type earlier, like this:

```
var x = snapshot.value! as Map;
```

So this confirms that `snapshot.value` isn't `null` with an `!` again, and then also ensures you get back a `Map`, which your later code assumes.

---

You also have a blue hint under

```
if (snapshot != null) {
```

That probably tells you that `snapshot` can never be null. You'll want to instead check `snapshot.value` in there, and then swap the condition and the assignment to:

```
if (snapshot.value != null) {
  var x = snapshot.value! as Map;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to map snapshot.value to model class before access email id.

> User user = snapshot.value as User;